# Eclips output display language is symbols instead of english words

Tags: eclipse

I have a problem with the output display of both Eclips Luna and Netbeans. Everytime I run my application my output comes out with symbols that I do not understand instead of plain English. My machines locale language is set to English and I made sure that when i downloaded these programs it was the english version.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: It may help to see your code

Comment: I am still new to all this, but even on a basic code like this my output comes out with symbols or a different language. import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class HelloDialog 
{

 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello World!");

 }

}

Answer (score 0):

add the -Duser.language=en parameter in the eclipse.ini file

Comment: I have done that but It still displays in a different language. My whole IDE is in English, it is just when I run my program that it displays incorrectly.

Comment: I would like to see your code and the output if it is possible in a screen shot

Comment: Unfortunatley I cannot post screen shots yet. This is happening on both Netbeans and Eclips so I wonder if it could possibly be my JDK. version 1.

Comment: I don't think so. it has to be something related to your eclipse and NetBeans. I would suggest try installing the software again.